# CSS compiled wrongly when using a SASS mixin

Tags: html, css, sass, mixins, node-sass

When i include a mixin for an html element, the html element comes out nested inside the mixin style in the compiled css.

The compiled CSS below throws error because the first property of @font-face is a '**.myDiv**'.
(not sure how it got inserted inside during compilation).

**// INPUT SASS //**

```
@mixin font-face($font-name, $font-path) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: $font-name;
    src: url('#{$font-path}');
  }
}

.myDiv {
  @include font-face('custom', 'assests/fonts/custom.woff');
  width: 100px;
}
```

**// OUTPUT CSS //**

```
   .myDiv {
      width: 100px;
    }

    @font-face {
      .myDiv {
        font-family: "custom";
        src: url("assests/fonts/custom.woff");
      }
    }
```

**Thanks !!**

Comment: It's single woff. I will change it. The result is still the same.

Comment: why are you declaring a font-face inside a class ? are you trying to scope it so that it is only available for that class ? im asking because your normally declare them somewhere at the begining of the css and just set font-family later to use the font

Comment: @Dirk Yes, I want specific font-family for specific html class as I have multiple elements that used different fonts (some from web, some local). So, i wanted to create a general mixin rule that accepts url and font-family name.

Comment: your are mixing how this works, you have to define `@font-face`and use the defined on as `font-family` like here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face#Examples

Comment: @Dirk Yes, but this way I have to write `@font-face { }` rule with atleast 2 more nested property for every html element which is a lot of repeated code. You think there is other way for a more DRY solution?

Comment: Something like this is what I want: https://gist.github.com/jonathantneal/d0460e5c2d5d7f9bc5e6#file-_mixins-scss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`font-face` is not a property which you set to an element. You need to import it in your css file and the use the `font-family` property on the element.

see code below

```css
@mixin font-face($font-name, $font-path) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: $font-name;
    src: url('#{$font-path}');
  }
}
@include font-face('custom', 'assests/fonts/custom.woff');
 
.myDiv {
  font-family: custom;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  assss
</div>
```

Comment: @Minhai T  I guess this is the only way (ie. without using the standard '@font-face' rule). In this codepen (https://codepen.io/davidpollet/pen/ORyYap), I saw that you could include it, so I tried that way. Guess not. Thanks

Comment: Actually I need @font-face because without it, the font cannot be loaded as the 'src' is now set as a style for the html element instead of fetching it.

Comment: Wow, this works. Font are loaded and applied correctly. So the trick was to declare the mixin name as a global font-face variable and expand it inside the desired html element (not sure if i expressed it right).

Comment: Glad i could help ! Cheers ! :D